# Showing data in DataGridView based on specific text box

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have a C# program that logs jobs by a user and the logged job gets sent to a Service Based Database.
I am able to get my data displaying in the DataGridView without any problem, however each of the items in the database are assigned to a username. I want the person who is logged into the application to view only their logged jobs in the database.

So is there anyway to show the data in the table based on a username that is stored in a text box? The username is stored in txtUsername.Text;

This is the code i have to display the data in the table.

```
private void DisplayData()
    {
        string constring = @"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\listm\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\EnviroWaste Job Logger\EnviroWaste Job Logger\UsersDatabase.mdf;Integrated Security=True";
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constring))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM LoggedJobs", con))
            {
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
                {
                    using (DataTable dt = new DataTable())
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            sda.Fill(dt);
                            //Set AutoGenerateColumns False
                            tblLoggedJobs.AutoGenerateColumns = true;

                            //Set Columns Count
                            tblLoggedJobs.ColumnCount = 7;

                            //Add Columns
                            tblLoggedJobs.Columns[0].Name = "JobID";
                            tblLoggedJobs.Columns[0].HeaderText = "Job ID";
                            tblLoggedJobs.Columns[0].DataPropertyName = "JobID";

                            tblLoggedJobs.Columns[1].Name = "JobDate";
                            tblLoggedJobs.Columns[1].HeaderText = "JobDate";
                            tblLoggedJobs.Columns[1].DataPropertyName = "JobDate";

                            tblLoggedJobs.Columns[2].Name = "UserID";
                            tblLoggedJobs.Columns[2].HeaderText = "User ID";
                            tblLoggedJobs.Columns[2].DataPropertyName = "UserID";

                            tblLoggedJobs.Columns[3].Name = "IssueSubject";
                            tblLoggedJobs.Columns[3].HeaderText = "IssueSubject";
                            tblLoggedJobs.Columns[3].DataPropertyName = "IssueSubject";

                            tblLoggedJobs.Columns[4].Name = "Screen";
                            tblLoggedJobs.Columns[4].HeaderText = "Screen";
                            tblLoggedJobs.Columns[4].DataPropertyName = "Screen";

                            tblLoggedJobs.Columns[5].Name = "FurtherInformation";
                            tblLoggedJobs.Columns[5].HeaderText = "FurtherInformation";
                            tblLoggedJobs.Columns[5].DataPropertyName = "FurtherInformation";

                            tblLoggedJobs.Columns[6].Name = "JobStatus";
                            tblLoggedJobs.Columns[6].HeaderText = "JobStatus";
                            tblLoggedJobs.Columns[6].DataPropertyName = "JobStatus";

                            tblLoggedJobs.DataSource = dt;
                        }
                        catch (Exception e)
                        {
                            MessageBox.Show("Not working");
                        }

                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

[image: SQL Table Details]

Comment: Consider the use of a DataView.  You can filter data there iirc.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I managed to fix my issue by using C# Parameters.
Thanks to all of you who posted answers.

```
public void DisplayData()
    {
        string constring = @"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\listm\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\EnviroWaste Job Logger\EnviroWaste Job Logger\UsersDatabase.mdf;Integrated Security=True";
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constring))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM LoggedJobs WHERE (UserID = @userID)", con))
            {
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserID", txtUserID.Text);
                using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
                {
                    using (DataTable dt = new DataTable())
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            sda.Fill(dt);
                            //Set AutoGenerateColumns False
                            tblLoggedJobs.AutoGenerateColumns = true;

                            //Set Columns Count
                            tblLoggedJobs.ColumnCount = 7;

                            //Add Columns
                            tblLoggedJobs.Columns[0].Name = "JobID";
                            tblLoggedJobs.Columns[0].HeaderText = "Job ID";
                            tblLoggedJobs.Columns[0].DataPropertyName = "JobID";

                            tblLoggedJobs.Columns[1].Name = "JobDate";
                            tblLoggedJobs.Columns[1].HeaderText = "JobDate";
                            tblLoggedJobs.Columns[1].DataPropertyName = "JobDate";

                            tblLoggedJobs.Columns[2].Name = "UserID";
                            tblLoggedJobs.Columns[2].HeaderText = "User ID";
                            tblLoggedJobs.Columns[2].DataPropertyName = "UserID";

                            tblLoggedJobs.Columns[3].Name = "IssueSubject";
                            tblLoggedJobs.Columns[3].HeaderText = "IssueSubject";
                            tblLoggedJobs.Columns[3].DataPropertyName = "IssueSubject";

                            tblLoggedJobs.Columns[4].Name = "Screen";
                            tblLoggedJobs.Columns[4].HeaderText = "Screen";
                            tblLoggedJobs.Columns[4].DataPropertyName = "Screen";

                            tblLoggedJobs.Columns[5].Name = "FurtherInformation";
                            tblLoggedJobs.Columns[5].HeaderText = "FurtherInformation";
                            tblLoggedJobs.Columns[5].DataPropertyName = "FurtherInformation";

                            tblLoggedJobs.Columns[6].Name = "JobStatus";
                            tblLoggedJobs.Columns[6].HeaderText = "JobStatus";
                            tblLoggedJobs.Columns[6].DataPropertyName = "JobStatus";

                            tblLoggedJobs.DataSource = dt;
                        }
                        catch (Exception e)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine(e.StackTrace);
                            MessageBox.Show("Not working");
                        }

                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all according to my opinion you dont have to create seprate admin table to manage admins .. if your system has more than one admin.. catogerize your users !! you can manage admin in your user table

And the answer to your question is :
    string query="Select userId from TableUSer where userName= {0}",textbox.text;

```
connecion=new connection     
sql command=new command(query,connection);

using (sqldatareader reader=command.executerreader)
while(reader.read())
{

 int userId=reader.getint32(0)

 }
connection.close();
```

now pass this userId to your logged table in query to get the user JObs

Comment: I adjusted my SQL Query to this: using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM LoggedJobs WHERE UserID=" + txtUserID.Text, con)) however it threw an error.

Comment: as you said above you are getting text from textbox that may be textbox.text="any name" and you are passing id as parameter ,, try passing username as parameter and if loggedjob doesnot contains username then try getting userID against that userName from your user Table and then pass that id to loggedjobs table

Comment: i have edit my answer ..try using above queries hope that help

Comment: Can you rewrite your answer using the Code: tool so i can understand it a bit better? Thanks